# Issues with threads in Ruby Test::Unit?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, unit-testing, testunit

I'm doing some frontend tests on a web app using Ruby's Test::Unit.  Are there any awkward race conditions in Test::Unit if I use multithreading in the tests?

For instance, if I want to run a test on 200 different pages, it would be very nice to parallelize it so that the tests might run in 1 second rather than 200 seconds.

So far, it seems like there IS a race condition in the code that counts the number of assertions (if I have an assertion within the multithreaded section, then it will say that there was one assertion rather than 200 assertions), but I haven't been able to uncover any other issues (where there is an error, it always notices).

Thanks!

Comment: Is it practical to move the assertion itself out of the multithreaded section?

Comment: The error message would be less descriptive than desirable if I moved the assertion out.  If the only race conditions are the ones that I have already discovered, I'm fine with them, and I'll keep the code as-is.  If there are other race conditions that I haven't discovered, then there could be other issues, so I would still like to know about how Test::Unit is.  Also, I plan on doing other multithreaded things in my unit tests where it won't be practical to move the assertions outside (assuming it doesn't cause any big issues).